# domain.com/sub redirecting to sub.domain.com/sub

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, subdirectory

My main page is WordPress, I have a forum installed on a sub-directory. I've set up a sub-domain at `forum.domain.com`.

Going to the sub-domain works fine, but going to `domain.com/forum` redirects me to `forum.subdomain.com/forum` which is a tad annoying but not website breaking.

I've been fiddling around with `.htaccess` and `mod_rewrite` stuff but I'm new to it so I'll probably end up making lasagna instead of working URLs. Both my homepage WordPress installation and my forum have `.htaccess` files for their own `mod_rewrite` stuff.

Any help, insight, and enlightenment is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve that by using this rule in the root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub\.domain\.com/sub$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^sub/$ http://sub.website.com/sub [L,NC,R=301]
```

This rule first checks if you're on the subdomain, if you are, then nothing happens. If you are not on `sub.domain.com/sub` then it will redirect you to it.

Make sure you clear your cache before you test this.

**EDIT**

I've re-read your question a number of times and now I feel like the above is not the answer you're looking for. I feel like you're trying to redirect from `sub.domain.com/sub` to `sub.domain.com` ? If that is the case, you will need to use this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com/sub$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^sub/$ http://sub.website.com [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: @Dylan Roberson After re-reading your question a few times. I now believe that is _**not**_ the answer you're after. Your question is quite confusing.. what is it you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry for the confusing question, I'm a confusing person. I'm trying to go from domain.com/sub to sub.domain.com, which I've set up, DNS and everything. But for some weird reason it instead goes to sub.domain.com/sub and I'm just trying to cut off the /sub at the end of sub.domain.com/sub when going to domain.com/sub. It's a weird confusing issue, and I apologize

Comment: @DylanRoberson It is no problem Dylan haha. Try the second rule that I've written in my edit. That should fix your problem.

Comment: Hm I really need to learn .htaccess syntax. Also the weird issue still persists, and at this point I believe it's my forum software doing something strange. Maybe it hates me, who knows. But I really appreciate your help and I'll be looking around to see if it is indeed forum software related. Thanks again.

Comment: Hmm this is a strange one... do you have any other rules in your `.htaccess`? But like you said, it _could_ be a setting that you have set up on your forum.